# A manipulator with gripper for simulation

Tags: ros, gazebo, moveit, gripper, manipulation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am experimenting with high level manipulation tasks and wish to see the results in simulation. I would like to use Moveit for motion planning and observe the simulated results in Gazebo.

*I need some suggestions on manipulators with a simple gripper as its end-effector* (2 finger like PR2 will do just fine).

I tried to use a pr2 gripper with ur5 but I think I am not able to get the controllers right. Also the motion planning gets really weird in moveit after adding the gripper.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/255700/a-manipulator-with-gripper-for-simulation/) by [Sumit Dey](https://answers.ros.org/users/27553/sumit-dey/) on ROS Answers with karma: 83 on 2017-02-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

what about [fetch simulation](http://docs.fetchrobotics.com/gazebo.html) ?

---

Originally posted by [Oscar Lima](https://answers.ros.org/users/21475/oscar-lima/) with karma: 831 on 2017-02-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Sumit Dey](https://answers.ros.org/users/27553/sumit-dey/) on 2017-02-27**:
Bit lighter on computational cost would be better. Just a manipulator would be good instead of entire robot with sensors and all.